# Swift DispatchQoS.QoSClass conversion to DispatchQueue.Attributes

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to parameterize the quality of service of a dispatch queue I would like to create in Swift 3.  I am trying to do this but get an error:

```
let qos:DispatchQoS.QoSClass = .background // ok
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue", attributes: qos) // error on `qos`
```

The error is: `Cannot convert value of type 'DispatchQoS.QoSClass' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue.Attributes'`

How can I make the conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the second line with

```
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"myqueue", qos:qos)
```